# How to display loading progressbars for each recyclerview in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a screen with two `recyclerviews` (one horizontal and other vertical) in it, Now when user comes to this screen i'm doing a rest call to fill data to both of the recycler views.one rest call for horizontal recyclerview and another rest call for second recyclerview.

My problem is how do i show spinning circular progress for horizontal recycler view and spinning circular progress for vertical recycler view.because both rest calls are independent i don't want to display only one progressbar for entire activity.

I don't have any code that i have tried.

Comment: what type of data you want to display in each recyclerviews

Comment: so just start the progressbar at the start of webservice call and stop it at the end of the call what is the issue here ??

Answer (score 1):

In your layout file where you define the recyclerview, put a progressbar on top of each recyclerview, when loading data, the progressbar will appear, and after loading complete, set the visiablity of the progressbar to `VIEW.INVISIABLE`

Comment: Good Idea, but how do i make circular progress centered(Not setting gravity to horizontal center), as i'm in a nested scrollview.

Comment: You can nested the recyclerview and progressbar in a `RelativeLayout` first and then put it to the scrollview.

Comment: Because you have a complex requirement :)

Answer (score 1):

When you hit your rest api, use `View.VISIBLE` on your progressBar to indicate data loading and after filling data to your recyclerView2, use `View.GONE` on your progressBar to hide it.

Comment: I dont want progressbar for each recyclerview item, i want a progress for the entire recyclerview untill i fill data into it

Answer (score 0):

The detailed layout is up to your arrangement.

`layout/my_layout.xml`

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pb_vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/rv_vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" 
    />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pb_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/rv_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" 
    />
```

`MyActivity.java`

```
private void showVerticalContent() {
    // when vertical content is fetched
    pb_vertical.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    rv_vertical.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void showHorizontalContent() {
    // when horizontal content is fetched
    pb_horizontal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    rv_horizontal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```